# python syntax error when trying to create an sqlalchemy database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I created a website on my PC using python 3.8 and i am having to move it onto a development server, which uses python 2.7 which i a can not update as its for a course i am on, when i developed the code i used 'f' to print the data but i am not sure how to change what i have got so it will work on python 2.7.
below is the code parts i need to change.

```
 def __repr__(self):
        return f"Member('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Share('{self.title}', '{self.share_date}')"
```

also this is what i get in response from the command line

```
from flaskproject import db
/home/40317391/submission-project.git-/Blog/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:834: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "flaskproject/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from flaskproject import routes
  File "flaskproject/routes.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flaskproject.forms import SignUpForm, LoginForm, EditHubForm, ShareForm
  File "flaskproject/forms.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flaskproject.models import Member
  File "flaskproject/models.py", line 20
    return f"Member('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: *f-string* were introduced after python 3.6 version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 def __repr__(self):
        return "Member('" + self.username + "', '{self.email}')"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Share('" + self.title + "', '" + self.share_date + "')"
```

Comment: thank you this worked but now i have a new issue when trying to import Member and share it says,                                                                                                                    
from flaskproject import Member, Share
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Member

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 doesn't support f-strings, but you could use simple format strings:

```py
return "Member('%s', '%s')" % (self.username, self.email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main code was in python3 :
As of Python3, f-strings are a great way to format strings .so your code :

`f"Member('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"`

works fine on your system.

your server is python2,

f-strings is not included in python2. so you can not use the string formator.
you have to use the old syntax :

`"Member('" + self.username + "', '{self.email}')"`

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "Member('" + self.username + "', '{self.email}')"
    
    def __repr__(self):
       return "Share('" + self.title + "', '" + self.share_date + "')"
```

by the way, both syntaxes will show the same result, just different versions of python, support different things.

if I did not understand your answer, please comment or reply, so that I get it correctly. thanks.

Comment: thank you this worked but now i have a new issue when trying to import Member and share it says,                                                                                                                    from flaskproject import Member, Share                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name Member

Comment: can you send the error message more elaborately . as I did not get the proper understanding of what the issue is. 

as you know as per documentation, Any version of Python higher than 2.7 is necessary to install SQLAlchemy. so are you sure , your server has SQLAlchemy installed .

please check that, also send a full error message and if possible, git repo of the latest code. 

I will try my best. Upvote if the answer above helped you, it will definitely help me to reach other developers. thanks

Comment: its python 2.7.17 i belive sqlalchemy to be installed

Comment: This is a link to a new post I created with the problem I have got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63208292/i-am-getting-an-error-while-trying-to-create-my-database-in-python